# Executing scala code from a jar, clarification needed

Tags: java, scala, maven

I have a maven project, which produces 1 jar file at the end. Project contains 2 modules, of which one is Java and the other one is Scala.

Scala module uses Java code for some backend things. In my example, Java is actual logic, Scala is business rules.

This is how I am executing my code. Neither way i am trying works

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:**

```
scala -cp /usr/share/scala/lib/scalatest_2.11-2.2.4.jar org.scalatest.tools.Runner -p '/home/program-201504.22-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/me/git/program/scala/target/scala-program-201504.22-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/me/temp/lib/.' -o -fWDF /home/me/git/program/scala/target/surefire-reports/TestSuite.txt -u /home/me/git/program/scala/target/surefire-reports/. -s a.b.engine.driver.MyClass
```

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:**

```
scala -cp /usr/share/scala/lib/scalatest_2.11-2.2.4.jar:/home/program-201504.22-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/me/temp/lib/.:/home/me/git/program/scala/target/scala-program-201504.22-SNAPSHOT.jar org.scalatest.tools.Runner -p '/usr/share/scala/lib/scalatest_2.11-2.2.4.jar:/home/program-201504.22-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/me/temp/lib/.:/home/me/git/program/scala/target/scala-program-201504.22-SNAPSHOT.jar' -o -fWDF /home/me/git/program/scala/target/surefire-reports/TestSuite.txt -u /home/me/git/program/scala/target/surefire-reports/. -s a.b.engine.driver.MyClass
```

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**

```
scala -cp /usr/share/scala/lib/scalatest_2.11-2.2.4.jar org.scalatest.tools.Runner -R "/home/program-201504.22-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/me/git/program/scala/target/scala-program-201504.22-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/me/temp/lib/." -o -fWDF /home/me/git/program/scala/target/surefire-reports/TestSuite.txt -u /home/me/git/program/scala/target/surefire-reports/. -s a.b.engine.driver.MyClass
```

Please help me understand what am I doing wrong.

1. I confirmed that a.b.engine.driver.MyClass exists in /home/me/git/program/scala/target/scala-program-201504.22-SNAPSHOT.jar